# Calculating width of knockout rendered components

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I'm using knockout to render a list of clickable elements that function as radio buttons. However, as this is a list with the elements listed horizontally, it can run off the page to the right when too many elements are put in (as they can be at times). Right now, I just have it breaking and making multiple rows, but this is not ideal for the design I want to have.

The problem is that the components I am inserting have variable width, depending on the name of the person listed in each component. What I would like to do is be able to tell how many components I can put for the given browser width, then hide the rest in a different observable array that I can render in a different manner (using a dropdown). I don't believe there is any easy way for me to use CSS to do this, as it would have to be rendered in an entirely different element.

The code in my ViewModel looks something like this:

```
self.personList = ko.observableArray(params.personList);

self.visiblePersons = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    var viewPortWidth = $("#personListContainer").width();
    var personArray = [];
    $.each(personList(), function(person) {
        var widthOfPersonElement = getPersonWidth(person); //not sure how to get the person width after render?
        viewPortWidth -= widthOfPersonElement;
        if (viewPortWidth >= 0) {
            personArray.push(person);
        }
    });
    return personArray;
});

self.overflowPersons = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    //get all persons in the person list that AREN'T in the visible list
    //this is the easy part
});
```

I guess my question is, is this even realistically possible? I would like to avoid having to render it, then get each element's width, then re-render again or something messy/flickery like that. I know that in order for it to dynamically update when the window is resized, I'd have to add a trigger for the element, but I can't even figure out how I'd do this first step.

EDIT: So, I poked around a bit and ended up deciding that I'd have to use the dom. The solution I have looks something like this:

```
var getRenderedPersonWidth = function(person) {
    var displayString = person.FullName + person.ID;
    var element = document.createElement('span');
    $(element).text(displayString);
    $(element).addClass(""); //class names of the element I'm rendering
    $('#elementtorenderunder').append(element);
    var width = $(element).width();
    $(element).remove();
    return width;
}
```

It actually works quite well, though you'd have to keep the classes updated in sync with the html you're rendering in. Not pretty, but it's the best I have for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: So, I poked around a bit and ended up deciding that I'd have to use the dom. The solution I have looks something like this:

```
var getRenderedPersonWidth = function(person) {
    var displayString = person.FullName + person.ID;
    var element = document.createElement('span');
    $(element).text(displayString);
    $(element).addClass(""); //class names of the element I'm rendering
    $('#elementtorenderunder').append(element);
    var width = $(element).width();
    $(element).remove();
    return width;
}
```

It actually works quite well, though you'd have to keep the classes updated in sync with the html you're rendering in. Not pretty, but it's the best I have for now.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to do this by working with your model, because your problem is DOM-dependent, and the viewmodel doesn't know what its relationship is to the DOM. You could be rendering the same data in multiple places.

You need a [custom binding handler](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html) when you want to control how data is rendered. It is realistically possible, but it is a complicated problem.

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up using the dom temporarily in order to figure it out. I see your point about it being dom-agnostic.